# Use UTF-8 for Angular 4 Routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I use Angular2/4 route for Persian(farsi) language and I pass the categories name with params of the route for showing the categories in url. this is generated link style:

```
<a _ngcontent-c1="" ng-reflect-router-link="posts,4,سرگرمی" href="#/posts/4/%D8%B3%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%85%DB%8C"> سرگرمی</a>
```

i need the href shows سرگرمی after id of that category no the

> **%D8%B3%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%85%DB%8C**

Comment: If you doesn't matter active state of a link, you could make a href manually

Answer (score 1):

Try to  enable html5 mode, below is for Angular 1.x

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`

It actually works fine with `{{mylink}}` binding, see this angular 4.3.5 example:

`<a href="/posts/4/{{mylink}}">This is a persian link</a>`

https://plnkr.co/edit/76G4dQuQ3QEQMXXaNiRq?p=preview

Comment: I've searched for this option but do not found anything.. any idea?